# Will there be star sizing in future versions of HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css

In WPF you can set the width of a column to occupy the remaining space by setting the width to a star. Will there be something similar in future versions of HTML or CSS?

Example:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50px;">
  Occupies 50px of the page width
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 1*;">
  Occupies 25% of the rest of the page width
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 3*;">
  Occupies 75% of the rest of the page width
</div>
```

It would really help web developers out there if this could be implemented in future versions of browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [template layout module for CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-layout/) that does something similar.

---

**Edit**    But you can already do that:

```
<div style="padding-left: 50px">
    <div style="float: left; width: 50px; margin-left: -50px;">
        Occupies 50px of the page width
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 25%">
        Occupies 25% of the rest of the page width
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 75%;">
        Occupies 75% of the rest of the page width
    </div>
</div>
```

The additional `padding-left` and `margin-left` adjustment is to have the content model of the outer `DIV` at 100% minus 50px width.

Comment: The template layout module looks really promising! The current solution you are suggesting solves my problem perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can already achieve this in HTML...

Here's your example, adjusted to work in just HTML.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50px;">
  Occu- pies 50px of the page width
</div>
<div style="margin-left: 50px; width: 100%;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 25%">
      Occupies 25% of the rest of the page width
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 75%;">
      Occupies 75% of the rest of the page width
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make it 100% wide, but jutting out to the right by 50px?

Comment: @Charlie Somerville: It needs some additional tweaking but it works already.

Answer (score 2):

The W3C's CSS Working Group has accepted a proposal for a percent minus pixels feature which could be used to the same effect as the star feature.

It could work like this, although I'm not certain

```
.fixedCol {
    width:200px;
}
.fluidCol {
    width:100% minus 200px;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure they implemented this as `width: calc(100% - 200px)`. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)